# PHPExcel : Can we make use of it in our comercial web server

Tags: licensing, phpexcel

Can I make use of PHPExcel software for my commercial web site - https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/license

I am not sure of all terms defined in the URL

Comment: Yes you can, that LGPL license is basically giving you the rights to use PHPExcel in any website or product, even to change the PHPExcel code if you wish, and about the only requirement of the license is that you don't change the credits to exclude the original developers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this page](https://tldrlegal.com/license/gnu-lesser-general-public-license-v2.1-(lgpl-2.1)) for a simple explanation of what you can/can't do under the LGPL 2.1 license.... use in commercial products is basically the first thing on that list

Quick Summary:

> You may copy, distribute and modify the software provided that modifications are described inside the modified files and licensed for free under LGPL-2.1. Derivatives works (anything statically linked) of the software must be licensed under LGPL, but separate, parent projects don't have to be.

**You Can**

- Commercial Use
- Modify
- Distribute
- Sublicense

**You Cannot**

- Hold Liable

**You Must**

- Include Original
- Include Copyright
- Include License
- Disclose Source
- State Changes
- Include Notice

Comment: Thanks Mark a lot. As I understand if I am developing a commercial software for my clients which includes PHPExcel - then only during the software installation in client's web server I would need to render the must categories. We have no intention to re-distribute the same but since the code is in PHP we would need to include it in our release in our client's web server box.

Comment: The basic restriction is that when you install it on your clients box as PHP source, you also need to install files like `license.md`

Comment: I am sorry Mark but I understand along with PHPExcel code I need to install license.md file in same directory where we are deploying PHPExcel. Can you please let me know the content / format of license.md and any other that is required along with it

Comment: The license.md file is in the root folder for PHPExcel - https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/license.md